# How to remove separator line in jfree chart- donut chart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am creating Donut chart using Jfreechart. I want to remove separator line (ie.line between green section and white section)- This line is exceeding the chart part. i need to restrict that to just to chart width.

Below is the actual and expected chart:
[image]

In this added image you can clearly see the extented section break line outside the chart pie.(marked in blue circle). i need to get rid of that extended line , the section break line should not go beyond the actual pie area.

Any one help me to achieve these.

Below is the code i'm using:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PiePlotState;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.RingPlot;
import org.jfree.data.general.DefaultPieDataset;
import org.jfree.data.general.PieDataset;
import org.jfree.text.TextUtilities;
import org.jfree.ui.ApplicationFrame;
import org.jfree.ui.RectangleInsets;
import org.jfree.ui.RefineryUtilities;
import org.jfree.ui.TextAnchor;
public class DonutChart extends ApplicationFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    static class CustomRingPlot extends RingPlot {

        private Font centerTextFont;    
        private Color centerTextColor;

        public CustomRingPlot(PieDataset dataset) {
            super(dataset);
            this.centerTextFont = new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.BOLD, 24);
            this.centerTextColor = Color.BLACK;
        }

        @Override
        protected void drawItem(Graphics2D g2, int section,
                Rectangle2D dataArea, PiePlotState state, int currentPass) {
            super.drawItem(g2, section, dataArea, state, currentPass);
            if (currentPass == 1 && section == 0) {
                Number n = this.getDataset().getValue(section);
                g2.setFont(this.centerTextFont);
                g2.setPaint(this.centerTextColor);
                TextUtilities.drawAlignedString(n.toString(), g2,
                        (float) dataArea.getCenterX(),
                        (float) dataArea.getCenterY(),
                        TextAnchor.CENTER);
            }
        }
    }

    public DonutChart(String title) {
        super(title);
        setContentPane(createDemoPanel());
    }

    private static PieDataset createDataset() {
        DefaultPieDataset dataset = new DefaultPieDataset();
        dataset.setValue("A", 71);
        dataset.setValue("B", 29);
        return dataset;
    }

    private static JFreeChart createChart(PieDataset dataset) {
        CustomRingPlot plot = new CustomRingPlot(dataset);
        JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart("",
                JFreeChart.DEFAULT_TITLE_FONT, plot, false);
        plot.setBackgroundPaint(null);
        plot.setOutlineVisible(false);
        plot.setLabelGenerator(null);
        plot.setSectionPaint("A", Color.RED);
        plot.setSectionPaint("B", Color.WHITE);
        plot.setSectionDepth(0.5);
        plot.setSectionOutlinesVisible(true);
        plot.setSectionOutlinePaint(Color.RED);
        plot.setShadowPaint(null);
        return chart;
    }

    public static JPanel createDemoPanel() {
        JFreeChart chart = createChart(createDataset());
        chart.setPadding(new RectangleInsets(4, 8, 2, 2));
        ChartPanel panel = new ChartPanel(chart);
        panel.setMouseWheelEnabled(true);
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 300));
        return panel;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RingChartDemo1 demo = new RingChartDemo1("JFreeChart: Ring Chart Demo 1");
        demo.pack();
        RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(demo);
        demo.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your example does not compile, and your invocation of `setSectionOutlinePaint()` is deprecated; please [edit] your question accordingly. Also, restore the copyright and cite the [original](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The observed lines are the so-called "separator" lines. [`RingPlot`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/RingPlot.html) has several methods to control them; amongst them, see [`setSeparatorsVisible(boolean)`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/RingPlot.html#setSeparatorsVisible-boolean-).

By calling `plot.setSeparatorsVisible(false)` in your method `createChart()`, you can hide those lines.

[image]